# Using elastic beanstalk to deploy .net web app and connect to remote db

Tags: .net, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been trying to get my .net web application working on elastic beanstalk for the past 2 days.

I can't get the app to connect to my remote database hosted in Azure SQL database.

The errors are:
[Win32 exception]
The network path was not found. A network related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a connection.

[Entity Exception]
The underlying provider failed to open

[Http Exception]
The underlying provider failed to open

I can run the code from my local computer.
I can connect to the database from the MSSQL management studio inside the instance.
I have allowed 1433 on my instance security group both inbound and outbound

My connection string: "data source=[dbserver],1433;user id=[username];password=[password];initial catalog=[default_db];persist security info=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework"

Any idea why I cant still connect to the database?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if you're using [Azure SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/) (hosted/managed version of SQL Server running on Azure) or a dedicated SQL Server running on a VM on Azure. You mention Network Security Group so I'd favor the later option otherwise you may look for [some guidance here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings/).

TCP/443 is the minimum port to open to access a SQL Server database **running over TCP**. However the error you mention: `[Http Exception] The underlying provider failed to open` relates to **HTTP**, it may means that somehow you try to access your remote SQL Database using a HTTP endpoint. In this case, you'd need to open port TCP/80 (or TCP/443 if using HTTPS endpoint).

Another possible cause of error is that you've open port TCP/443 in your Network Security Group but you forgot to open this same port on the local firewall running on your SQL Server instance (see [this page for more details on how to configure your windows firewall for SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023(v=sql.120).aspx)).

Comment: Hey seb, thanks for your help. The problem is I have to open secure tcp port on my elasticbeanstalk instance :)